# Entity Framework Code First With Oracle Database

Tags: asp.net, oracle, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

i am working on a project that requires to be developed using Entity Framework Code First Approach with a local oracle database, but when i am attempting to reflect my first (Initial) model changes to the database using migrations, the package manager console throws the following error Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleException (0x80004005): ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 1
ORA-08177: can't serialize access for this transaction

- database used: oracle 11g  Visual Studio 2015
  Oracle.
- ManagedDataAccess v 18.3.0
- Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework v 18.3.0

any help will be appreciated,,,

Answer (score 0):

Solved by downgradin oracle managed data access and oracle M A EF to 12.2.21